# Calculating line intersections with Python gave unexpected result

Tags: python, coordinates, linear-algebra, intersection, vertex

I have a ray casting program that finds the intersections of a ray and the edges of a polygon. In my code snippet below, I have the ray and edge in the form y = mx + b of a line. I defined a square by its vertices `((50, 50), (50, 70), (70, 70), (70, 50))` and casted rays towards each vertex and my program calculated intersection with every vertex except `(70, 70)` and `(70, 50)`. For the latter case, the ray seemed to "slip past" this vertex and intersect with the line passing through the points `(50, 50)` and `(50, 70)` at an unexpected point `(49.99999999999999 16.666666666666643)`. To clarify, here are all the intersections my program detected:

```
(50.0, 50.00000000000001) # Ray was cast towards (50, 50)
(50.0, 70.0) # Ray was cast towards (50, 70)
(50.0, 50.00000000000001) # Ray was cast towards (70, 70). Also unexpected
(49.99999999999999, 16.666666666666643) # Ray was cast towards (70, 50) Unexpected intersection value
```

In my objects.py file:

```
from math import atan, pi

class Ray:
    def __init__(self, origin, direction):
        self.origin = origin
        self.direction = direction  # radians

        self.endpoint = None

        self.hit = False

    def set_endpoint(self, point):
        self.endpoint = point

    def set_hit(self):
        self.hit = True


class Line:
    def __init__(self, endpoint1, endpoint2):
        self.p1 = endpoint1
        self.p2 = endpoint2

    def direction(self):
        delta_x = self.p2[0] - self.p1[0]
        delta_y = self.p2[1] - self.p1[1]

        if delta_x == 0:  # Undefined slope

            if delta_y > 0:
                return pi / 2

            else:
                return 3 * pi / 2

        else:
            return atan(delta_y / delta_x)


class Polygon:
    def __init__(self, vertices):
        self.vertices = vertices


    def edges(self):
        edges = []

        for i in range(len(self.vertices)):
            # We mod the endpoint point of the line by the amount of vertices
            # since we want the endpoint of our last edge to be the first vertex
            edges.append(Line(self.vertices[i], self.vertices[(i + 1) % len(self.vertices)]))

        return edges
```

And in my caster.py file:

```
from ART import objects
from math import tan


class ShadowCaster:
    def __init__(self, source, polygons):
        self.source = source
        self.polygons = polygons
        self.rays = []

        print(self.polygons)

    def cast_rays(self):
        for polygon in self.polygons:
            for vertex in polygon.vertices:
                direction_to_vertex = objects.Line(self.source, vertex).direction()
                ray = objects.Ray(self.source, direction_to_vertex)

                self.rays.append(ray)

    def process_endpoints(self):
        for ray in self.rays:
            for polygon in self.polygons:
                for edge in polygon.edges():
                    # We are given the endpoints and direction of both the ray and the edge. Find intersection.
                    # We want to obtain the general form y = mx + b for the ray and edge.

                    # Given: y, m, x; solve for b
                    # b = y - mx

                    if not ray.hit:
                        ray_x = ray.origin[0]
                        ray_y = ray.origin[1]
                        ray_m = tan(ray.direction)

                        ray_b = ray_y - ray_m * ray_x

                        edge_x = edge.p1[0]  # Using either p1 or p2 is fine since the line passes through both.
                        edge_y = edge.p1[1]
                        edge_m = tan(edge.direction())

                        edge_b = edge_y - edge_m * edge_x

                        # General case
                        # {y = ax + b
                        # {y = cx + d
                        #
                        # => ax + b = cx + d
                        # => x(a - c) = d - b
                        # => x = (d - b) / (a - c) therefore y = a((d - b) / (a - c)) + b

                        intersect_x = (edge_b - ray_b) / (ray_m - edge_m)
                        intersect_y = ray_m * intersect_x + ray_b

                        print(intersect_x, intersect_y)

                        ray.set_endpoint((intersect_x, intersect_y))
                        ray.set_hit()
```

The loop that I run:

```
caster = engine.ShadowCaster(origin=(100, 100), polygons=[objects.Polygon(((50, 50), (50, 70), (70, 70), (70, 50)))])


while 1:
    caster.cast_rays()
    caster.process_endpoints()
```

Any suggestions on what I might have done wrong?

Comment: Please edit the code in your question into a [mre] including data, imports, etc. - I should be able to paste the code (preferably in one single piece of code not interspersed with descriptive text unless in Python comments)  into a file and __without adding anything__ run it to see the same error you are seeing.

Comment: For example, what coordinates is ray.origin?

Comment: The origin of the ray is (100, 100)

Comment: The rest of my code is simply renders everything based on the data I process in the code given

Comment: That’s why you need to make a [mre] - there’s obviously slmething wrong with your algebra/line calculation, and without a simple example that shows the problem it’s all guessing.

Comment: Don’t need anything to render - need a __minimal__ example that shows the calculation problem.

Comment: I have tried to give a minimal example as best as I can. It is in the question now! I have removed the rendering bits

Comment: Your question is still quite verbose with too much unnecessary context. Simplify it more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a disappointing amount of messing about to get your "minimal reproducible example" to run, and doing some debugging, the issue is missing logic: you aren't in fact testing whether the intersection point you find between the line of the ray and the line of the edge is in fact within the line segment of the edge - you just assume the first intersection is a hit, i.e. the unconditional:

```
ray.set_endpoint((intersect_x, intersect_y))
ray.set_hit()
```

and as soon as this first intersection has been "found" then no further intersection tests are done, although your code continues to iterate over them which seems unnecessary. Anyway the result is you are only ever showing "intersections" with the first edge of the polygon.

To fix this you need to add a test of intersection of the ray with the edge. You need to allow for floating point (im)precision and rounding i.e. intersection being calculated as just an eensy weensy distance outside the extents of the edge (but not if that would be a better intersection with another edge).

BTW one problem with using the general form y=mx+b is it isn't robust when the line is ~vertical - given you have two points on each line you might be safer using the parametric form y=p*(y2-y1)+y1 and x=p*(x2-x1)+x1 where 0.0<=p<=1.0 which happily can also make detecting intersection easier without using trigonometric functions ref below the heading "Given two points on each line" here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection

Also if you have to use line directions then using `math.atan2` is more robust than `math.atan` for describing line directions - you don't have to code guard for vertical line where dx is ~0, and because it knows the signs of dy and dx it knows the quadrant of the line direction and returns a value in range +/-pi

Comment: Thanks for all that feedback! I thought my question had been ditched haha! Anyways, I will attempt to update my "intersection confirmation" logic and switch to a different general form for a line.

Comment: I do have one more question, though: How come the vertices at (50, 50) and (50, 70) were detected? Shouldn't the logic stay constant throughout?

Comment: I think it’s because the second ray to 50,70 intersects with the first edge from 50,50 to 50,70 at 50,70 on the first edge but you read this as 50,70 on the second edge.